# Help me write a Clojure macro which automatically adds metadata to a function definition

Tags: lisp, clojure, macros, defn

I realize that the first rule of Macro Club is Don't Use Macros, so the following question is intended more as an exercise in learning Clojure than anything else (I realize this isn't necessarily the best *use* of macros).

I want to write a simple macro which acts as a wrapper around a regular `(defn)` macro and winds up adding some metadata to the defined function.  So I'd like to have something like this:

```
(defn-plus f [x] (inc x))
```

...expand out to something like this:

```
(defn #^{:special-metadata :fixed-value} f [x] (inc x))
```

In principle this doesn't seem that hard to me, but I'm having trouble nailing down the specifics of getting the `[args]` and other forms in the defined function to be parsed out correctly.

As a bonus, if possible I'd like the macro to be able to handle all of the disparate forms of defn (ie, with or without docstrings, multiple arity definitions, etc).  I saw some things in the [`clojure-contrib/def`](http://code.google.com/p/clojure-contrib/wiki/DefApiDoc) package that looked possibly helpful, but it was difficult to find sample code which used them.

Comment: Good intro... major props for that.

Comment: Why not use macros?  Are you thinking of the C preprocessor?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Updated:**

The previous version of my answer was not very robust.  This seems like a simpler and more proper way of doing it, stolen from `clojure.contrib.def`:

```
(defmacro defn-plus [name & syms]
  `(defn ~(vary-meta name assoc :some-key :some-value) ~@syms))

user> (defn-plus ^Integer f "Docstring goes here" [x] (inc x))
#'user/f
user> (meta #'f)
{:ns #<Namespace user>, :name f, :file "NO_SOURCE_PATH", :line 1, :arglists ([x]), :doc "Docstring goes here", :some-key :some-value, :tag java.lang.Integer}
```

`#^{}` and `with-meta` are not the same thing.  For an explanation of the difference between them, see Rich's discussion on the [Clojure mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/msg/919455504c57659e).  It's all a bit confusing and it's come up a bunch of times on the mailing list; see also [here](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/6182a1f8a9139abc/df6d7670bb390358) for example.

Note that `def` is a special form and it handles metadata a bit oddly compared with some other parts of the language.  It sets the metadata of the `var` you're `def`fing to the metadata of the symbol that names the var; that's the only reason the above works, I think.  See the `DefExpr` class in `Compiler.java` in the Clojure source if you want to see the guts of it all.

Finally, page 216 of [Programming Clojure](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/shcloj/programming-clojure) says:

> You should generally avoid reader macros in macro expansions, since reader macros are evaluated at read time, before macro expansion begins.

Comment: Interesting!  But is there a way to do it more functionally?  Wrapping a `defn` in a `do` and then destructively modifying its metadata seems kind of weird to me.  Then again, my experiments with using the `#^{:k :v}` syntax from inside a `defmacro` have all been utter failures so far...

Comment: Doing any kind of `def` is not a very functional thing to do, since it destructively mutates the state of a global dispatch table.  :)  But you're right, and I've updated my answer.  My previous answer was dropping the #^Integer tag metadata that a `def` would normally take.

Comment: Thanks, this is a lot more understandable and those links look very helpful, although I'm still a bit mystified about why (macroexpand-1 '(defn-plus foo [bar] (baz))) doesn't display the with-meta tag.

Comment: Try (set! *print-meta* true) and then look at the macro expansion.  You'll see the metadata has been applied to the symbol that names the function.  `with-meta` is executed in the body of the macro, before the macro returns.  Note that it's un-quoted in the macro.